# asp.net MVC where do controller methods should go for nested view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have folder structure like  this in my mvc project. I have a sub folder called 'Student' under 'School' , where do I need to write controller methods for that?

```
---Views (Folder)
-----School (Folder)
-----SchoolView.cshtml
-------Student (Folder)
-------StudentView.cshtml

---Controller (Folder)
-----CustomerController.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make **School** as **[Aera](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**. There is an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/601504/Using-areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC-to-organize-a-project).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is more a matter of personal style. In my practice it depends whether the partial view will bre used in more than one view, if not I'll put the action in the same controller as the parent.